# Rails 3: object.save is writing the old values to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have code which is updating a model's property then calling `save!`. A `Rails.logger.info` call shows that the model thinks it has the new values. But the SQL write performed by the `save!` call is writing the old value to the database.

At first it wasn't writing anything to the database at all when I called `save!`. I thought it was that the object wasn't thinking its value had changed for some reason: `changed?` returned false, so I used a `_will_change!` notification to force a write. But now it is doing a write, but with the old values.

This doesn't happen from the "rails console" command line: there I'm able to update the property and it will return `changed?` of true, and let me save successfully.

Excerpt from the server log follows. Note that the object thinks it has `log_ids` of **'1234,5678,1137'**, but writes to the database **'1234,5678'**.

> current log ids are [1234, 5678]
>   new log ids are [1234, 5678, 1137]; writing log_ids of '1234,5678,1137' to NewsList 13 with dirty true
>   SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "news_lists" SET "log_ids" = '1234,5678', "updated_at" = '2012-01-02 02:12:17.612283' WHERE ("news_lists"."id" = 13)

The object property in question is `log_ids`, which is a string containing several IDs of another kind of object.

The source code that produced the output above:

```
def add_log(new_log)
  new_ids = get_log_ids
  Rails.logger.info("current log ids are #{new_ids}")
  if new_ids.length >= NewsList.MAX_LENGTH
    new_ids.shift
  end
  log_ids_will_change!
  new_ids.push new_log.id
  log_ids = new_ids.join ","
  Rails.logger.info("new log ids are #{new_ids}; writing log_ids of '#{log_ids}' to NewsList #{id} with dirty #{changed?}")
  save!
end
def get_log_ids
  if log_ids 
    log_ids.split(",").map &:to_i 
  else
    []
  end
end
```

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here?

Comment: If it's ActiveRecord don't you need to access DB properties through self and not just "bare" variables because of how AR works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the self to `self.log_ids = new_ids.join ","` otherwise you will just be assigning to the local variable (namesake) instead of the db-persisted attribute (column).

Comment: Wow. I'd never encountered that particular quirk of ActiveRecord before. I didn't know there was any difference at all between those two syntaxes, but yes, that fixes it. Why does it create a namesake local variable?

Comment: When you assign to a setter you must always be explicit and add `self`, otherwise the interpreters creates a local variable, it has no way to know whether you want to create a local var or call the setter, so default behavior is to create a local var. For getters is different because if it does not find a local var with that name in the scope, it tries to call that method, so for getters we need not to prefix with self.